# Solution Verification: Disproving a claim about the interior of the image of the closure of a closed mapping

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, closed-map

$
\newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand}
\nc{\SS}{\mathcal{S}}
\nc{\TT}{\mathcal{T}}
\nc{\ol}{\overline}
\nc{\inv}[1]{#1^{-1}}
\nc{\int}{\operatorname{int}} 
\nc{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
$
**Setup:** Suppose we have two topological spaces, $(X,\TT)$ and $(Y,\SS)$. Let $f : X \to Y$ be a closed mapping (i.e. maps closed sets to closed sets).

Suppose that, for some $y \in Y$ and a corresponding $G \in \TT$ ($G$ open in $X$), we have that $\inv f(y) \subseteq G$.

Our goal is to prove or disprove the following claim: $y \in \int (f(\ol{G}))$.

---

**My Attempt:** I think I've found a counterexample, but I just wanted to double-check it.

Consider the case of $f : \R \to \R$ with $f(x) \equiv 0$. We will use the usual topology on $\R$.

$f$ is clearly a closed mapping (all closed sets will map to $\{0\}$, which is closed).

Take $y = 0, G = \R$ in the statement of the claim. Then $\inv f(0) = \R \subseteq \R \in \TT$ trivially.

However,
$$
\int (f(\ol{G})) = \int(f(\ol{R})) = \int(f(\R)) = \int (\{0\}) = \emptyset
$$
and thus cannot contain $0$.

---

**My Question:** Is this correct? It just feels a little too easy (especially after struggling for a while to instead prove the claim), so I feel like I must've missed something important.

Comment: That looks correct to me.